# Error con login en laravel

Tags: laravel

Me encuentro haciendo un login desde cero en laravel , pero al momento de ingresar no me arroja error ni nada por el estilo, me redirecciona al mismo login, el codigo del formulario en mi vista es el siguiente:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/verificar') }}">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Usuario</label>
                 <input name="usuario" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Usuario">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Contraseña</label>
                 <input type="password" name="password"class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Ingresar</button>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" ><a style="color:#ffffff;"href="{{ route('registro') }}">Registrar</a></button>
           </form>
```

La ruta con el metodo post es:

```
Route::post('/verificar','loginController@login');
```

y en mi controlador tengo una funcion la cual agregue el siguiente codigo:

```
public function login()
{
    $credenciales=$this->Validate(request(),
        [
            'usuario'=>'required|unique:tbl_usuario',
            'password'=>'required|min:6'
        ]);
    if (Auth::attempt($credenciales))
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }else{
        return back()
            ->withErrors(['usuario'=>trans('auth.failed')])
            ->withInput(request(['usuario']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104068/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-monroy-rodriguez-error-con-login-en-laravel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que se obtuvo fue la siguiente, en la vista login se realizo cambio el tipo de los botones ya que se tenian dos botones tipo submit, quedando el codigo así

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/verificar') }}">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Usuario</label>
                 <input name="usuario" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Usuario">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Contraseña</label>
                 <input type="password" name="password"class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Ingresar</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ><a style="color:#ffffff;"href="{{ route('registro') }}">Registrar</a></button>
           </form>
```

La ruta quedo igual y el cambio mas importante fue en el controlador, primeramente se creo un seeder para ingresar los datos y mandar nuestra contraseña con hash

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\tbl_usuario;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        tbl_usuario::create(array(
            'usuario'  => 'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make('admin') // Hash::make() nos va generar una cadena con nuestra contraseña encriptada
        ));
    }
}
```

Complementando el seeder se hizo el cambio en el archivo por defecto que trae laravel "DatabaseSeeder" quedando así

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\YourClassName;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       Eloquent::unguard();

        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

    }
}
```

Y en nuestro controlador habia confusion porque estabamos poniendo un validate cuando lo necesario era autenticar dejando nuestro controlador así :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class loginController extends Controller
{
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
  {
   return view('lab');
  }else{
   return "error";
  }
    }
 
}
```